# Сортировка строкового массива по количеству слов в строке

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Необходимо отсортировать массив строк по количеству слов в каждом элементе массива, от меньшего к большему количеству. Например есть такой массив:

```
{ "hello my world", "Hello world", "Hello", "Hello world this is me" };
```

После сортировке должно быть:

```
{ "Hello", "Hello world", "hello my world", };
```

Но получается не совсем то что нужно:

```
    String[] stringArray =
    { "hello my world", "Hello world", "Hello", "Hello world this is me", "Hello world this is me and you" };
    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < stringArray.length; j++)
        {
            StringTokenizer sTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(stringArray[i]);
            int tokens = sTokenizer.countTokens();
            if (stringArray[j].compareTo(stringArray[i]) < tokens)
            {
                String temp = stringArray[j];
                stringArray[j]=stringArray[i];
                stringArray[i]=temp;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(stringArray[i]);

    }
```

Я подсчитываю количество слов в каждой строке а потом меняю элементы местами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опустим пока вопрос об эффективности, вы делаете

```
StringTokenizer sTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(stringArray[i]);
int tokens = sTokenizer.countTokens();
```

Вы получили количество слов в `i` элементе массива. Дальше вы делаете

```
if (stringArray[j].compareTo(stringArray[i]) < tokens
```

Уже выглядит мягко говоря странно.

Пишите примерно так

```
StringTokenizer sTokenizerL = new StringTokenizer(stringArray[i]);
int tokensL = sTokenizerL.countTokens();
StringTokenizer sTokenizerR = new StringTokenizer(stringArray[j]);
int tokensR = sTokenizerR.countTokens();
if ( tokensL < tokensR)
   //swap
```

Но реализация крайне неэффективная.
Я бы лучше сделал как-то так

```
class Pair implements Comparable {
    public int tokenCount;
    public String string;
    public Pair(String string){
        this.string = string;
        StringTokenizer sTokenizer = new  StringTokenizer(string);
        tokenCount = sTokenizer.countTokens();
    }
    public int compareTo(Object obj){
        Pair other = (Pair)obj;
        return tokenCount - other.tokenCount;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return string;
    }
}
```

И использовать его для сортировки через стандартный метод `Arrays.sort`

Comment: Спасибо! @pavel

Answer (score 1):

Не самое оптимальное решение, но наиболее короткое

```
       Arrays
            .stream(array)
            .sorted((c1, c2) -> Integer.compare(c1.split("\\s").length, c2.split("\\s").length))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```